# array.push() method is not adding anything to array and working weirdly

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-console

I am new to programming and also **stackoverflow**.
My problem is related to `array.push()` method in `JavaScript`.
See the code first

```
var buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var gamePattern = [];
gamePattern = gamePattern.push(nextSequence());

function nextSequence(){
        var randomNumber = Math.floor( Math.random() * 4);
        var randomChosenColor = buttonColors[randomNumber];
        return randomChosenColor;
}
```

Kindly check this image too...
[This is chrome console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shjnO.png)

The problem is that the `randomNumber` is being generated properly and `randomChosenColor` is also getting the color properly but it is not being pushed in `gamePattern` array at line number **3**. Also help me if there is some alternative to this method.

Comment: `push` returns the number inserted, not the new array. The push happens in-place.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: The code you posted does not create the output in the screenshot. If you still need help after debugging your code, please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push changes the original state of the array. So you don't need to re-initialize the array.

```
 var buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
    let temp=[];
    temp.push(seq());
    console.log(temp);
    function seq(){
        var randomNumber = Math.floor( Math.random() * 4);
        var randomChosenColor = buttonColors[randomNumber];
        return randomChosenColor;
    }
```

Comment: Thank You Brother, you have solved my problem. Please tell me what is this "let" keyword that you have added

Comment: "let" keyword is used for variable declaration it is block scoped . To read about it more . You can refer this document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Answer (score 0):

[`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) mutates the original array (and returns the new length), so you don't need to assign a new value to `gamePattern`. Try something like this:

```
var buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var gamePattern = [];
gamePattern.push(nextSequence());

function nextSequence(){
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  var randomChosenColor = buttonColors[randomNumber];
  return randomChosenColor;
}
```